# how to set add button at right side of after recently added image in android?

Tags: android

I want to add button right side of image( which is recently added image).

I am using below code to add a button on click button images are adding one by one right side of previous image .

But i want to add button should always appear right side of previously added image and click then image should appear in place of button and button should just appear right side of image again and again.

as per below sample image

[image: sample image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Button"
        />



    <neeraj.com.images.PredicateLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp">
    </neeraj.com.images.PredicateLayout>









</LinearLayout>


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    PredicateLayout predicate;
    Button button1;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //linearLayout1 = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
        predicate = (PredicateLayout) findViewById(R.id.image_container);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);





        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ImageView image = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                image.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                predicate.addView(image);

            }
        });


    }


}
```

PredicateLayout

```
public class PredicateLayout extends ViewGroup {

    private int line_height;

    public PredicateLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public PredicateLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        assert (MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec) != MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

        final int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

        // The next line is WRONG!!! Doesn't take into account requested MeasureSpec mode!
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec) - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();
        final int count = getChildCount();
        int line_height = 0;

        int xpos = getPaddingLeft();
        int ypos = getPaddingTop();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                final LayoutParams lp = child.getLayoutParams();
                child.measure(
                        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
                        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

                final int childw = child.getMeasuredWidth();
                line_height = Math.max(line_height, child.getMeasuredHeight() + lp.height);

                if (xpos + childw > width) {
                    xpos = getPaddingLeft();
                    ypos += line_height;
                }

                xpos += childw + lp.width + 8;
            }
        }
        this.line_height = line_height;

        if (MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) {
            height = ypos + line_height;

        } else if (MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            if (ypos + line_height < height) {
                height = ypos + line_height;
            }
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height + 20);
    }

    @Override
    protected LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
        return new LayoutParams(2, 2); // default of 1px spacing
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean checkLayoutParams(LayoutParams p) {
        return (p instanceof LayoutParams);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        final int count = getChildCount();
        final int width = r - l;
        int xpos = getPaddingLeft();
        int ypos = getPaddingTop();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                final int childw = child.getMeasuredWidth();
                final int childh = child.getMeasuredHeight();
                final LayoutParams lp =  child.getLayoutParams();
                if (xpos + childw > width) {
                    xpos = getPaddingLeft();
                    ypos += line_height;
                }
                child.layout(xpos, ypos, xpos + childw, ypos + childh);
                xpos += childw + lp.width + 8;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some code for ```PredicateLayout``` and some code that you use for adding the images, would help a lot .

Comment: If it takes the whole width (adding too many images) then what do you want? keep the images in same line or expand them to next line?

Comment: I'll suggest you use a RecyclerView with HORIZONTAL orientation. Each time the add image is clicked you refresh the list. NOTE- Use notifyItemInserted(position) instead of notifyDataSetChanged(). Clean, efficient & easy to implement.

Comment: use pagination concept in horizontal way

Answer (score 0):

you can use horizontal  recycler view and imageview and use static arraylist after click image if possition is last add +1 in arralist and notify adapter you will get exactly what u want.

Comment: typing in all caps amounts to shouting

Comment: Horizontal recycle view will not add image in next row if row is filled

Comment: you can again make recycler view first add one more item in array and using notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged()  it will create again adapter

Comment: pagination you have to do whith recycler view

Comment: in my above code images are coming one by one I want to set add button should appear just after image

Comment: ya use imAGE OR BUTTON NO ISSUE DO  ONE THING IN ON BIND VIEW HONDER IN RECYCLER VIEW TACK POSSITION CHECK IF ARRAYLIST POSSITION AND recyclerview adapter POSSITION IS LAST CHANGE THE BUTTON OR IMAGE WHITH SIMILLER TO YOUR ADD BUTTON

Comment: your requerement is just one if else in onbindview holder